# Keeping track of form in sports with R?

Tags: r

To keep up with a teams current form, I want to know how they performed over the last N-matches. The data starts likes this:

```
HomeTeam   AwayTeam  Winner 

Liverpool  Chelsea   Home
Arsenal    Liverpool Away
Manchester Liverpool TBA
```

Say for example I want to know the form over the last 2 matches before the 3th match starts, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
HomeTeam   AwayTeam  Winner HomeForm AwayForm

LiverPool  Chelsea   Home   NA       NA
Arsenal    Liverpool Away   0        1
Manchester Liverpool TBA    0        2
```

I have looked at both LAG and IF/ELSE functions, but I can't seem to find a solutions that looks up the results dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a simpler hack, but you could try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

last_n_games <- 2

df <- df %>% rowid_to_column

Forms <- df %>%
  mutate(Winner = case_when(Winner == "Home" ~ HomeTeam, 
                            Winner == "Away" ~ AwayTeam,
                            TRUE ~ "TBA")
  ) %>% 
  gather(Team, name, HomeTeam:AwayTeam) %>%
  distinct(rowid, name, Winner) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(rowid) %>%
  mutate(
    HomeForm = +(Winner == name),
    HomeForm = rollapply(HomeForm, width = list(-(1:last_n_games)), sum, 
                              partial = TRUE, fill = NA, align = "right"),
    AwayForm = HomeForm
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("Form")), funs(ifelse(rowid != 1 & is.na(.), 0, .))) %>%
  distinct(rowid, name, HomeForm, AwayForm)

df %>%
  left_join(Forms %>% select(-AwayForm), by = c("rowid", "HomeTeam" = "name")) %>%
  left_join(Forms %>% select(-HomeForm), by = c("rowid", "AwayTeam" = "name")) %>%
  select(-rowid)
```

Output:

```
    HomeTeam  AwayTeam Winner HomeForm AwayForm
1  Liverpool   Chelsea   Home       NA       NA
2    Arsenal Liverpool   Away        0        1
3 Manchester Liverpool    TBA        0        2
```

Oh, and I forgot - this presumes that your data frame doesn't have spelling mistakes (do you really have `Liverpool` as `LiverPool` sometimes?).

If this wasn't just a typo, let us know, I'll adapt the code.

Comment: It seems however that it just scores the homeform or awayform per row, but doesnt sum them over multiple rows per team.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In the above example, the wins of Liverpool are indeed summed over multiple rows (first 2 in this case) for the last row.

Comment: I removed Plyr from the script, and now it works. Amazing! Thanks a bunch! Will mark as answered.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it works! And yeah, `plyr` can cause many issues these days. I avoid it when possible.